# XCode 4.3 crashes when adding Tab Bar Item (UITabBar)

Tags: uitabbar, ios5, crash, xcode4.3

Is anyone else having this issue when trying to add UITabBar item into an existing Tab Bar? Xcode simply freezes while the tab bar item is being dragged out from the object library, and then crashes.

Comment: I tried all sorts of workarounds, like restarting xcode, unplugging my iphone from the usb, etc. Seems to be a very consistent issue.

Comment: Ah, here's the solution: just option-click the existing tab bar items to make copies. This prevents the crash.

Comment: I get exactly the same problem. Sent a crash report to apple :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a month old, but in case you haven't done it, updating to the latest version of XCode should fix the problem.